# Unaccept on community wiki (bug)

Tags: support, status-bydesign, community-wiki

`unaccept` on community wiki still yields -15 reputation to the original poster, for instance "-15 11 hours ago unaccept".

However it actually does not change reputation but shows up in the reputation log. 
I am not perfectly sure, however I believe the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460005/554431) was made community wiki *after* it was accepted, in that regard the -15 rep. should have been factored into the rep. score. Now it just shows as -15 in the log only.

Even it's a minor bug I guess the entire reputation system doesn't not use the history logs but only the present state. If so, it should be resolved as a known issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's behaving correctly - you just need to look back further.  Like you said, it was made community wiki **after** being accepted, that means the user *did* get +15 rep at the time it was accepted.  That means upon reversing it they'll get a -15 accordingly.

If you look at [the post owner's reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554431/bestsss?tab=reputation) you see a +15 from the accept back on December 11th, and a -15 from the unaccept today, Jan 2nd.

If you *reaccept* (which is what happened) then the *new* vote simply has no impact, it is a 0 score since it was created *after* the post was made community wiki - meaning the new vote also doesn't show in the owner's rep history, since it had no net impact on their reputation.

Comment: this part I understand, it does show in the log "-15 rep". In any way it's a bug, it shall not show in the logs at least when there is *no* effect on the reputation. i.e the rep. is still the same.

Comment: @bestsss - There *was* an effect on their reputation, they lost 15 due to the unaccept (since they earned 15 from the original accept, when the post was *not* community wiki), is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Nick, no there is no rep. loss, I am the one w/ the unaccepted answer, so i am perfectly sure there was no rep. change.

Comment: @bestsss - Visit [/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation), I think you'll agree there's *exactly* a 15 rep difference that'll take effect on your next recalc...

Comment: it has been 4006 for days, it still shows the same. nothing has changed.

Comment: @bestsss - No, it doesn't...it shows "** total rep 3991 :)", did you actually visit the link in my last comment, or just ignore it to argue your point? :)

Comment: I did, i know it shows there. but on my screen it's 4006, ahh ok I had to click 'trigger', got that. still a bug imo

Comment: @bestsss - "rep sync" has lots of issues...we'll begin working on a major project to *finally* solve that hopefully tomorrow :)

Comment: fine, i'm to accept the answer; overall known issues as rep. sync